# Adding every last element in an array of arrays -rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have an array of arrays such as:-

```
 a=[["product1", "size1", "color1", "quantity1"],["product2", "size2", "color2", "quantity2"],["product3", "size3", "color3", "quantity3"]]
```

Now the above Array of arrays has quantity as last element in every array such as quantity1,quantity2,quantity3 and quantity4.i want to add every quantity(last element) to show total quantity ****such as quantity1+quantity2+quantity3+quantity4****
can i use inject() method,any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

```
total_quantity = a.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x.last }
```

Each `x` is one of your inner arrays. So  use `last` to get the last element of it.

**Disclaimer:** This works, if your last element in the inner array is a number. As in

```
a = [["product1", "size1", "color1", 1],["product2", "size2", "color2", 4],["product3", "size3", "color3", 3]]
```

Comment: getting error as String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Comment: This is because you use fake data in your example. To make that line work, you should use numbers for quanitity (or convert your strings to numbers). See the disclaimer in my answer.

Comment: a.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x.last.to_i }

Comment: @sub_total=items.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x.last }.....this worked for me.thanks 
Philipp Tessenow

Answer (score 1):

```
a.map{ |i| i.last.to_i }.inject(:+)
```

Comment: it concats the quantity such as "100100100"

Comment: that's because your quantities are stored as string. try `a.map{ |p|p.last.to_i }.inject(&:+)`

Comment: Thats because ur numbers are strings. updated my answer to make them integers